# How to compare timedelta in django template

Tags: django

From [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince),

I made testmodel like this:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I made a html code like this:

```
<p>It's made {{ user.testmodel.created|timesince }} ago</p>
<!-- and here is what I ask-->
<p>{% if user.testmodel.created|timesince > 72hours %}Too long time ago{% endif %}</p>
<!-- How can I do this part? -->
```

I want to compare `timedelta between now and testmodel.created` and `72 hours` on django template.

Is there any good way to do this on django template tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on server side [custom filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) is the way.

If you want to do it on client side [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) is the way.

Note : There are multiple alternatives available for **momentjs**.